# Python: Attribute in a class not being detected

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

```
class WeeklyTransactionData:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.raw_levels = df['Weekly Consumer Spending Levels'].copy()
        self.raw_growth = df['Weekly Consumer Spending Growth'].copy()
        self.standardized_levels = self.level(self.raw_levels.copy())
        self.standardized_growth = self.growth(self.raw_growth.copy())
        self.lower_levels = self.lower(self.standardized_levels.copy())
        self.median_levels = self.med(self.standardized_levels.copy())
        self.upper_levels = self.upper(self.standardized_levels.copy())
        self.months = {'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 
        'Apr': 4, 'May': 5, 'Jun': 6, 
        'July': 7, 'Aug': 8, 'Sep': 9, 
        'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12}    

def getMonth(self, entry): # This function helps us find the month corresponding to a date formatted for the Growth sheet
        abridged = entry[-10:]
        for i in self.months.keys():
            if i in abridged:
                return self.months[i]

def growth(self, df): # This cleans up the growth sheet

        last_month = self.getMonth(df.iloc[0][len(df.iloc[0])-1])
        print("Cleaning growth sheet")

        return df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Here are the relevant code. I deleted some confidential chunks from the growth function, but all that matters is the getMonth() method being called.

For some reason, I am getting an error that states that the WeeklyTransactionData class doesn't have an attribute *months*, but it is literally right there. why?

AttributeError: 'WeeklyTransactionData' object has no attribute 'months'

Comment: provide the DataFrame please, try to `print(self.months)` in the constructor

Comment: *How* are you calling `getMonth` and/or `growth`? At least in the question, neither is a method; they are  standalone functions (due to indentation issues). Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: chepner is right, indentation problem

Comment: Have you edited the file that defines `WeeklyTransactionData` to add the `months` attribute recently? You might have run the code without saving it or have a stale `.pyc` file lying around.